# Using Jquery for the first time

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement some jquery fade ins on my current project, this is my first time using it, and it wont implement. Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#appearingduo").fadeIn('slow'function(){
        });
  });</script>
</head>
```

As you can see I have the jquery library in an external javascript sheet, which I just copy and pasted from jquery.com, is this the right way to go about it?
Also what is being faded in is an image so in the css I set it to display:none, so then it could fade in, however it is doing nothing.
All help appreciated.
Ant

Comment: Why are you importing jQuery twice?

Comment: Is this also the first time you use JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

You've omitted a comma, to separate the different arguments passed to the method, it should look like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#appearingduo").fadeIn('slow',
        function(){
        });
  });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fyHQf/).

References:

- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a comma between `'slow'` and `function`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#appearingduo").fadeIn('slow'function(){
        });
   });
```

should be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#appearingduo").fadeIn('slow', function () {
       // fade has finished
   });
});
```

If you noticed I cleaned up the formatting a bit. If you keep a clean and consistent format then you will make less mistakes like forgotten commas, mismatched parathesis, etc.